# Refactor code to populate a spreadsheet

Tags: java

My code looks ugly. What can you recommend? I already know about `Enum`; maybe it's a good variant for this situation.  Anything else?

```
   private void writerContent(Integer firstRow, List<Record> records){
        int firstColumn=0;
        int lastColumn=7;
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        for (int lineId=firstRow;lineId<records.size();lineId++)   {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(lineId);
            for (int columnId=firstColumn;columnId<lastColumn;columnId++){
                switch (columnId){
                    case 0:  row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(records.get(lineId).getNumber()); break;
                    case 1:  row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(records.get(lineId).getName());  break;
                    case 2:  row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(records.get(lineId).getCode());   break;
                    case 3:  row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(records.get(lineId).getCount());  break;
                    case 4:  row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(records.get(lineId).getSimultaneouslyProcessedProducts());  break;
                    case 5:  row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(records.get(lineId).isSimultaneousProcessing());   break;
                    case 6:  row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(records.get(lineId).getInterchangeability()); break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gnanz's answer has a great tip for your method, but I just wanted to go over some more general style points for Java.

```
private void writerContent(Integer firstRow, List<Record> records) {
```

In general, method names should be actions and verb phrases.  The name `writerContent` is a noun phrase.  Perhaps this is simply a typo, where `writerContent` was supposed to be `writeContent`, though.

More importantly: why are you passing in an `Integer` object instead of the `int` primitive type as your first parameter?  Usually you should only do this if there is a very good reason to do so.  As it stands, your method is vulnerable to a `NullPointerException` if it is called incorrectly.  If you simply use an `int`, you remove this danger without sacrificing any functionality.

If you really want to keep the object wrapper, at least do some sanity checking (either at the beginning of your method or when you use it).  You can check for `null` and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or simply default to `0`, depending on how you want to design it.

```
if(firstRow == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must supply a first row.");
}
```

... or ...

```
if(firstRow == null) {
    firstRow = 0;
}
```

... or, if you want to get fancy with the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java) ...

```
for(int lineId = firstRow == null ? 0 : firstRow; lineId < records.size(); lineId++) {
```

Moving on to the rest of your code...

```
int firstColumn=0;
int lastColumn=7;
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
```

You should try to use consistent style throughout your code.  Above, you switch between having spaces between your assignment operator (`=`) and not having spaces.  What I tell my coders is that it doesn't really matter which one you use, as long as you're consistent.  The vast majority of work that will be done on the code you write will be done by people who have never looked at it before in their lives trying to do maintenance, so consistency really helps.

```
for (int lineId=firstRow;lineId<records.size();lineId++)   {
```

This `for()` loop is a bit hard to scan because it's all pressed together.  Consider spacing it out: `for(int lineId = firstRow; lineId < records.size(); lineId++) {`

The rest of your code in the `switch()` block is adequately addressed by the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you unroll the inner loop?  So the final method will be like

```
private void writerContent(Integer firstRow, List<Record> records) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
    for (int lineId=firstRow; lineId<records.size(); lineId++) {
        Record rec = records.get(lineId);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(lineId);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rec.getNumber());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rec.getName());  
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(rec.getCode()); 
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(rec.getCount());
        row.createCell(4).setCellValue(rec.getSimultaneouslyProcessedProducts());  
        row.createCell(5).setCellValue(rec.isSimultaneousProcessing());
        row.createCell(6).setCellValue(rec.getInterchangeability());
    }
}
```